# C# to connect and consume Microsoft 365 Graph API

Tags: c#, powershell, microsoft-graph-api

I currently use `msolservice` for mail creation. I'd like use Microsoft Graph API, but I can't find the correct documentation for what I need to do in C#

In this code, I used the PowerShell libraries to connect to Microsoft Online Services. When it comes to importing the module, I'm not sure which module I should import to use `mgGraph`, and I'm uncertain if those PowerShell libraries already contain the `mgGraph` modules.

```cs
using System.Management.Automation.Host;
using Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands;

// Create Initial Session State for runspace.
InitialSessionState initialSession = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
initialSession.ImportPSModule(new[] { "MSOnline" });

// Create credential object.
PSCredential credential = new PSCredential(UserCredential.UserName, UserCredential.Password);

// Create command to connect office 365.
Command connectCommand = new Command("Connect-MsolService");
connectCommand.Parameters.Add((new CommandParameter("Credential", credential)));
```

Comment: Why are you using PowerShell commands from C#, rather than a REST API call or using the C# SDK?

Comment: Because I already had an infrastructure that uses PowerShell to manage and automate tasks in Office 365, instead of rewriting all the code from scratch to adapt it to the C# SDK or make REST calls, I chose to use PowerShell scripts since I already had experience with it.

Comment: Then why don't you just stick with your PowerShell scripts? Why are you trying to write PowerShell in C#?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't attempt to call Graph from C# using PowerShell. You might be able to get it working, but it will be both overly complex and overly fragile.

What you want to use is the [Microsoft Graph .NET SDK](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet). The SDK will be easier to work with and there is [extensive documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/overview?view=graph-rest-1.0) and [samples available](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/browse/?products=ms-graph&languages=csharp).

I would start with the excellent [Quick Start tutorial](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/quick-start).